# get data from wp-option and use in style.php and include it in header as css file

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i want to create an option for my custom theme that users could change theme color(like nav background).
i want get some data like color code (#000) from database and then use in a style.php file. after that include it in wp_head as a css file.
the problem is when i use this code :

```
wp_enqueue_style('style.php.css', '/functions/style.php');
```

i get this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function theme_get_option() in D:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-content\themes\theme\functions\style.php:6
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

use get_option() directly

```
get_option( string $option, mixed $default = false )
```

Parameters
$option
(string) (Required) Name of the option to retrieve. Expected to not be SQL-escaped.

$default
(mixed) (Optional) Default value to return if the option does not exist.

example
get_option('bg_color');

also, you can use this plugin to create an options page for your client
https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-options-pages/